# Server side generating charts on PHP (laravel) without JS. What is actual now?

Tags: php, laravel, charts

I want to create nice charts  on the server side using laravel and save them as PNG. Which libraries are currently relevant?
Thanks!

Comment: that's too broad, if you want to generate charts on the server Side then try pChart which is one of the few native PHP charting libraries out there.

Comment: thanks, but pChart has not been updated for several years..

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here charts using http://lavacharts.com/

```
$stocksTable = $lava->DataTable();  // Lava::DataTable() if using Laravel

$stocksTable->addDateColumn('Day of Month')
            ->addNumberColumn('Projected')
            ->addNumberColumn('Official');


$chart = $lava->LineChart('MyStocks', $stocksTable);
```

Comment: I asked about "server side", "without JS"